# Projectile motion simulator in html/javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var theCanvas = document.getElementById("theCanvas");
var theContext = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
var theImage = document.getElementById("frog");
var ay = 9.81; //gravity constant in SI units
var dt = 0.2; //time step in seconds
var t = 0; //initial time
var vel = 45; //intial speed in meters per second
var yo = 450; //pixels from top to start 
var xo = 6; //pixels from left to start
var angle = 45 * Math.PI / 180; // 45 degrees converted to radians
var vx = vel * Math.cos(angle);
var vy = vel * Math.sin(angle);
var x = xo; //position at t=0
var y = yo; //position at t=0
var colDiam = 100; //collagen count

function launchProjectile() {
  moveProjectile();
}

function drawProjectile() {
  theContext.clearRect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);
  theContext.drawImage(theImage, x, y, 100, 100);
}

function moveProjectile() {
  if (y < 572) {
    t = +dt;
    x = (xo + vx * t) + colDiam * .0109;
    y = yo - vy * t + .5 * ay * (t * t);
    drawProjectile();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(moveProjectile);
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="width:1000px; float:left; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
  <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/uncharted/images/2/26/Amazon_rainforest_1.png/revision/latest?cb=20200519083419" width="1224" height="572" style="position:absolute;">
  <canvas id="theCanvas" width="1224" height="572" style="position:relative;">
    Canvas not supported; please update your browser.
  </canvas>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <input type="button" value="Launch!" onclick="launchProjectile();">
  </div>
</div>

<img id="frog" src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/41DF7DA0-EE58-4259-AA815A390FB37C55_source.jpg" width="100" height="100" style="position:relative;">
```

The issue is when I press the launchProjectile button, the projectile will draw but its x and y won't update. I think this probably lies in the `window.requestAnimationFrame(moveProjectile);` code, which originally used setTimeout(). When I changed it to requestAnimationFrame(), it still did not work however.

Comment: I've changed your code to a runnable snippet. Now please get it into a working state to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I'm confused what you're asking

Comment: Lee is saying, edit your code so that at least it runs without an error message. Then people can help you debug the movement problem.

Comment: @LeeTaylor should be fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `moveProjectile`, you were setting x equal to `xo + some other constants`.  Since `xo` never changed, you were just repeatedly setting x to `(xo + vx * t) + colDiam * .0109` on every single frame.  I changed this to `(x + vx * t) + colDiam * .0109` to "increment" x instead, which makes your frog picture move across the frame, which I guess is what you're probably going for.  Same thing as for `y`.

```js
var theCanvas = document.getElementById("theCanvas");
var theContext = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
var theImage = document.getElementById("frog");
var ay = 9.81; //gravity constant in SI units
var dt = 0.2; //time step in seconds
var t = 0; //initial time
var vel = 45; //intial speed in meters per second
var yo = 450; //pixels from top to start 
var xo = 6; //pixels from left to start
var angle = 45 * Math.PI / 180; // 45 degrees converted to radians
var vx = vel * Math.cos(angle);
var vy = vel * Math.sin(angle);
var x = xo; //position at t=0
var y = yo; //position at t=0
var colDiam = 100; //collagen count

function launchProjectile() {
  moveProjectile();
}

function drawProjectile() {
  theContext.clearRect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);
  theContext.drawImage(theImage, x, y, 100, 100);
}

function moveProjectile() {
  if (y < 572) {
    t = +dt;
    x = (x + vx * t) + colDiam * .0109;
    y = y - vy * t + .5 * ay * (t * t);
    drawProjectile();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(moveProjectile);
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="width:1000px; float:left; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
  <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/uncharted/images/2/26/Amazon_rainforest_1.png/revision/latest?cb=20200519083419" width="1224" height="572" style="position:absolute;">
  <canvas id="theCanvas" width="1224" height="572" style="position:relative;">
    Canvas not supported; please update your browser.
  </canvas>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <input type="button" value="Launch!" onclick="launchProjectile();">
  </div>
</div>

<img id="frog" src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/41DF7DA0-EE58-4259-AA815A390FB37C55_source.jpg" width="100" height="100" style="position:relative;">
```